# Same monthly result according to one date row context

Tags: powerbi

Explanation:

I need a measure to calculate the **real working days** of each month.
The dates dont account for the **holidays** so I defined a column that says "yes" or "no" if the date is a holiday in the database.
So having May with 31 days, the result I needed for that month, if I had one holiday, would be 30 working days. The total working days of the month need to be exacly the same because further I will calculate a daily target that has to be the same for each day of the respective month.

The problem is, I need to have a visual in a daily row context. So I have the correct monthly working days but when filtered in a **daily row context** only the date of the Holiday is correct (30 days), all the other dates get (31 days)

My measure:

```
Total NumberDaysMonth = 

VAR TotalDays = 
SUMX (
    SUMMARIZE (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            VALUES ( Tab_Origem[Data] ),
            "EOMonth", EOMONTH ( Tab_Origem[Data], 0 )
        ),
        [EOMonth]
    ),
    DAY ( [EOMonth] )
)
VAR NrHolidays = 
   SUMX(
    SUMMARIZE(
        Tab_Origem,
        Tab_Origem[Data],
        Tab_Origem[Holiday],
        "Count", COUNTROWS(Tab_Origem)
    ),
    IF( Tab_Origem[Holiday] = "Yes", [Count], 0)
)
RETURN
TotalDays - NrHolidays
```

Result:

| May | Total NumberDaysMonth |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 31 |
| 3 | 31 |
| 4 | 31 |

What I need:

| May | Total NumberDaysMonth |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30 |
| 2 | 30 |
| 3 | 30 |
| 4 | 30 |

I thought about some alternatives but neither worked because of the daily row context.
Any Help?
Thanks